# Scrolling background overlapped

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have long background for game so I have made two partition of it and started implementation of scrolling one after another.

But during scrolling, I was facing this kind of issue - one part get overlapped on other part, following image will give you more clearance about my point:

[image]

Because of overlapping problem, its not looking smooth.
Here is the code that I have used for implementation:

```
public class LayerScroller : MonoBehaviour
{

public Layer[] backgroundLayers;
public Layer[] starLayers;

void Start ()
{

}

void Update ()
{
//      for (int i = 0; i < backgroundLayers.Length; i++) {
//          backgroundLayers [i].MoveLayer ();
//      }

    for (int i = 0; i < starLayers.Length; i++) {
        starLayers [i].MoveLayer ();
    }
}
}

public class Layer : MonoBehaviour
{

public Transform prevGroupLayer;
public float speed;

public void MoveLayer ()
{

    Vector3 currPosition = transform.position;
    currPosition.y -= speed;
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, currPosition, Time.deltaTime * 10f);

 //     transform.Translate (Vector3.right * -speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (transform.position.y <= -GameConstants.BACKGROUND_LENGTH) {
        Vector3 currentPosition = transform.position;
        currentPosition.y = (prevGroupLayer.position.y + (GameConstants.BACKGROUND_LENGTH)) - speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = currentPosition;
    }
}
}
```

**LayerScroller** script is controlling all child layers and each layer contains **Layer** script.

Complete hierarchy looking like this:

[image]

Please give some guidance for solving this overlapping problem, definitely I am doing some small mistake.

Comment: I've had a similar issue. What i've done was; i created a big cylinder and assign the texture to it. And then rotated the cylinder which gives the illusion that background is moving/looping

Comment: Can you able to share code related to this?  so I can try from my side...